# div as button over element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div over a input field acting as a large clickable area. I'm using query to have a click event on the div. When I set the divs background-color:transparent in firefox everything works as planned which is the div gets the click and the input below it does not. but in IE the input filed below it is getting selected because IE treats it differently. How can I get around this IE issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting background-color to transparent, set opacity to 0, it will work in IE too.

css to set opacity in IE and other browser.

```
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop event propagation and bubbling when div is clicked can be solution.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the DIV element basically doesn't exist in IE (it's not being drawn) so there will be no event to stop the propagation of.